# Skip validation if required

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, error-handling

I have form with around 40 tabs and on each tab each input field gets compared with some limits. On clicking the next button I validate each tab and on error I don't let the user go to the next tab. Sometimes I need to let the user bypass the validation even with errors. I managed to get it working but the confirm dialog shows twice.

```
if (!error){
   //do abc
}else {
    confirm('Continue?');
    if (confirm('Continue?') == true) {
        //do abc
     }
     else return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling the confirm function twice. I'm assuming this will fix it:

```
if (!error){
   //do abc
}else {
    var confirmed = confirm('Continue?');
    if (confirmed) {
        //do abc
     }
     else return false;
 }
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. It's too soon to accept the answer. Will do it later. If possible could you give me a hint on how to have a input field in the confirm box so that a password would be needed to continue?

Comment: I believe that's not possible with the built-in confirm box. You could make a custom modal box with HTML and have it contain whatever inputs you like. You'd obviously need to control the interactivity with JavaScript still.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), a dialog box is going to show. Simply remove the first `confirm` call:

```
if (!error) {
    //do abc
} else {
    if (confirm('Continue?') == true) {
        //do abc
    } else return false;
}
```

Also, no need to compare to `true`, because it's already going to return a boolean:

```
if (!error) {
    //do abc
} else {
    if (confirm('Continue?')) {
        //do abc
    } else return false;
}
```